# How to access a java resource in a platform independent manner?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, file-access

I have placed a bitmap in /src/media/ and I am trying to access it in a manner that will work on all operating systems with:

```
ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/media/title.bmp"));
```

However I receive an exception when trying to execute my code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
```

Which implies that `this.getClass().getResource("/media/title.bmp")` returns null. Can you help me find my mistake?

Comment: Are you sure that the image is being copied to the same place as your .class files (output directory / jar file, etc.) ?

Comment: True! The file is not in the bin folder. I'm using eclipse, how to get the file to be copied?

Comment: Got it! Do you want to write an answer? in eclipse, right click the folder -> properties and include the files you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image needs to wind up in the same place as your .class files (I.e. in the classpath at runtime).

Most non-IDE build tools have a way to do this.
For example, in a Maven project, put it in src/main/resources

For a strictly IDE-based build, your IDE will probably have some way to configure this.